# What am I doing wrong for the import command to import data into a table in my database?

Tags: sqlite

I am in a entry level business analytics class and having trouble with this one command. Overall we have created a database and then a table within that database. I am attempting to import data from a CSV file into the table but the import comman isn't working. I can confirm the table is being created but nothing I do seems to want to import the data into the table. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
.open --new "C:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Databases/Superstore.db"

CREATE TABLE People 
(
  Person  Text ,
  Region  Text , 
  PRIMARY KEY (Region)
);

.tables
.separator ,
.import --csv --skip 1 c:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Data/People.csv People;

mode column
headers on

SELECT Person, Region FROM People;
```

I have tried the `select count(*) from People;` command in order to verify if the table has data in it and it keeps coming back as zero. At first I thought it was the select command that was messing up but now i am realizing there is nothing in the table to select. This has led me to realize that the issue is with the import command (At least I think) though I cant figure out what is wrong. I am rather new so there may be something obvious here that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated as Ive been looking at this for hours now.

Comment: have a look at this site did you search anywhere https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

Comment: Yes i looked quite a bit and already attempted replicating that very site. Even typing the same exact code on that site I still could not import. I eventually discovered the issue wasnt with the code at all but was with my computer. Every once in a while It just stops responding to code and I have to restart it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you follow the steps in my answer *exactly*, you will get the job done. It is tested & running code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after `.tables` command:

```
.mode csv
.import C:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Data/People.csv People
```

This works for me. My full command list to get the job done:

```sql
sqlite> .open --new "C:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Databases/Superstore.db"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE People (Person Text, Region Text, PRIMARY KEY (Region));
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import C:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Data/People.csv People
sqlite> Select Count(*) From People;
2
sqlite>
```

**EDIT:** To simplify things, you can create a small `People.csv` file *manually* whose content is:

```
Person1,Region1
Person2,Region2
```

This way we can be sure that the input CSV file is a valid one (I have used this file).

Comment: It looks like the Import function is doing something as i can see the file size increases when I run it. However whenever i run the SELECT Person, Region FROM People; command I dont get anything back; also the count command still comes back zero. I really dont know what to make of it.

Comment: Did you check that your input CSV file is *not empty*?

Comment: Yes I am certain it is not empty. It is a very small spreadsheet with only two columns and like 5 rows of data. I can open it and see that it has data though.

Comment: To confirm that your table has rows after the import, you can use the [SQLite DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/).

Comment: I downloaded DB browser and can see the table but the data is not. I even made a brand new file like you suggested and it went the same. I dont get an error or anything when I do the import command. Just nothing happens. Here is the exact code I am using copy and pasted: sqlite3


.open --new "c:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Databases/Superstore.db"

CREATE TABLE People 
(
Person  Text ,
Region  Text , 
PRIMARY KEY (Region)
)
;

.tables


.mode csv
.import C:/Business_Analytics/SQlite/Data/People.csv People;

.mode column
.headers on

SELECT Person, Region FROM People ;

Comment: Don't use `.tables` or `.mode` or `.headers` commands. Start by creating a text file named People.csv in your Data folder. Delete the Superstore.db file and **follow my steps exactly**. When you use the `CREATE TABLE` command you don't need to add header row in the CSV.